# How to change the size of the pixel in setPixel Function?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, drawing, picturebox

I want to change the size of the pixel in `setPixel` Function.

When I use `setPixel` Function. It drew a pixel. But it is very small.

Is there a way to change the size of the pixel in `setPixel` Function ?

I Remember in VB6 , There was a property in the properties of PictureBox called `DrawWidth`. In this property I can change the size of the drawing.

Maybe I have to use this property in VB.NET. But I did not find it in the properties of PictureBox in VB.NET.

Comment: You can fill a rectangular shape, [deriving a Graphics object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage) from the Bitmap -- If you instead need to replace multiple pixels at once, or multiple times, you better use [Bitmap.LockBits()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits) (copy the source image to a 32Bit ARGB Bitmap and modify this one)

Comment: Right...get a Graphics, make a Brush of the right color, then use one of the [FillRectangle()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fillrectangle?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) overloads.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you very much. I read the first article and it was very helpful. Now I can make my project.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Yes , I did this. And it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick option is to scale up a smaller image

```
'draw a small bitmap 
Dim bmp = New Bitmap(25, 25)
For y = 0 To 24
  For x = 0 To 24
    If x = y Then
      bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red)
    End If
  Next x
Next y
'scale it up 4x
Dim bmpBigger = New Bitmap(bmp, 100, 100)
PictureBox1.Image = bmpBigger
```

Output might be a bit fuzzy, though. To get exactly what you want you will need to use `Graphics` class

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked! Yes , the output was a bit fuzzy. This way was helpful. But I prefer using `Graphics`.